# Get a list of distinct values from one column in dynamic data where another column equals specific text?

Tags: excel-2019

I'm using SQL and Python to automatically populate a template Excel file with data each morning. In the Excel file, using the below table as an example, I need to get a distinct list of codes from the `Code` column, but only if the `New` column has a value of `Y`. This is an automated report that goes out each morning, so I can't do any manual data manipulation.

Existing Data Sample:

```
| New | Code |
| --- | ---- |
| N   | RTB  |
| N   | RTB  |
| Y   | RTB  |
| N   | SCR  |
| N   | SCR  |
| Y   | SCR  |
| Y   | SCR  |
| N   | SLD  |
| N   | SLD  |
| N   | SLD  |
| N   | RTS  |
| N   | RTS  |
| Y   | RTS  |
| Y   | RTS  |
| N   | CC   |
| N   | CC   |
```

There are five codes listed in the above table, but only three have a value of `Y` in the `New` column. I would like the following output:

```
| Code |
| ---- |
| RTB  |
| SCR  |
| RTS  |
```

Creating a pivot table and listing by `New` then by `Code` creates exactly what I need, but as I said above this has to be completely automated so the pivot table wouldn't work. I just can't figure out the right formula.

This formula gets me close, but using the above example, it would list all five codes:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(DATA!$B$2:$B$9999, MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF($A$1:A1, DATA!$B$2:$B$9999),0,0), 0))), "")` I don't know how to tell it to filter by the `New` column as well.

If there's an easier way to do this in Python or SQL then I'm good with that as well. I'm creating dataframes from SQL queries and writing them to excel to get the dynamic data mentioned above.

Thank you!

Comment: `select distinct Code from MyTable where New = 'Y';`?

Comment: You do need to pick the technology you want your answer in, because it can clearly be any of them which makes it impossible to say (based on the question) which is better.

Comment: All of my attempts so far have been in Excel, which is what I'd prefer, but if I have to use Python or SQL I'm fine with that.

Comment: In that case ask the question for Excel and if you don't get an answer ask a new question in Python. Don't ask one question that could have 3 totally different answers.

Comment: I gave you a SQL answer in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is happy to filter and uniquify those for you.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'New': list('NNYNNYY'), 'Code': 'RTB RTB RTB SCR SCR SCR RTB'.split()})
>>> sorted(df[df.New == 'Y'].Code.unique())
['RTB', 'SCR']
```

Feel free to use a method like
[.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) or
[.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)
to send those reporting results to the place where you need them.

Comment: I think I may go this route, though I'll have to create the dataframe from my imported SQL data rather that creating a manual list since the data is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Excel now has functions for this. Try:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Data!B:B, Data!A:A = "Y"))
```

Results:

```
| New | Code | Code |
| --- | ---- | ---- |
| N   | RTB  | RTB  |
| N   | RTB  | SCR  |
| Y   | RTB  | RTS  |
| N   | SCR  |      |
| N   | SCR  |      |
| Y   | SCR  |      |
| Y   | SCR  |      |
| N   | SLD  |      |
| N   | SLD  |      |
| N   | SLD  |      |
| N   | RTS  |      |
| N   | RTS  |      |
| Y   | RTS  |      |
| Y   | RTS  |      |
| N   | CC   |      |
| N   | CC   |      |
```

I am not sure what version introduced these relatively new functions. I found them referenced in [this article](https://www.fm-magazine.com/news/2018/dec/excel-functions-unique-filter-201820091.html), dated December 2018.  Seems a magnitude simpler than all the match, index, and relative referencing that the old techniques needed.

Comment: This answer would be preferable and is what I initially tried, but unfortunately Office doesn't introduce this feature until after 2019.